# Counting regex occurrences с++

Tags: c++, regex, std

I want to read the number of occurrences of a regular expression in a file. Well, I counted them, but the efficiency of the algorithm leaves much to be desired.

```
unsigned int FileAnalizer::regularCounter(std::string countingReg) {
    std::ifstream file(inputFilePath_, std::ios::in);
    if (!file) throw std::runtime_error("can't open file " + inputFilePath_);
    unsigned int counter(0);
    std::string line;
    std::regex  const expression(countingReg);
    while (std::getline(file, line)) {
        std::ptrdiff_t const match_count(std::distance(
            std::sregex_iterator(line.begin(), line.end(), expression),
            std::sregex_iterator()));
        counter += match_count;
    }
    return counter;
}
```

I think the fact is that the algorithm maintains matches and spends resources on allocation, but I do not need the resulting lines at all, can I somehow avoid this overhead?

Comment: Maybe storing whole file content instead of getting it line by line...

Comment: Hi, I have two small optimizations for you. 1) use optimized [regex](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/basic_regex) `const std::regex expression(countingReg, std::regex::optimize);` It will have slightly better run time, but slower construction. 2) You can define `std::smatch sm;` and change  your loop to `if (std::regex_match(line, cm, reg)) { counter++; }` . I think, it's more readable and it has slightly better performance. Your code has (-O3) 22385 intructions, with this change, it has 21734.

Comment: std :: regex_match - this is not what I need, the entries in the file should not coincide with the regular expression, but contain substrings that match the regular expression, these substrings, or words in the particular case, I need to subtract